# Evaluate $\int \frac{\operatorname{csch}^2\sqrt u}{\sqrt{u}}$

Tags: integration

I need to evaluate: $$\int \frac{\operatorname{csch}^2\sqrt u}{\sqrt{u}}$$

What I tried is write 
$$\operatorname{csch}^2\sqrt{u}=\coth^2\sqrt{u}-1$$
since the solution has a $\coth^2$ term, but I didn't go anywhere. I also tried to wrote out the formula for $\operatorname{csch}$ as 
$$\operatorname{csch} x=\dfrac{1}{\sinh x}=\dfrac{2}{e^x-e^{-x}}$$
still no clue about it... Any help? The solution is $-2\coth\sqrt{u}+c$

Comment: Substitute $x=\sqrt u$.

Comment: Every integral of the form $\displaystyle\int\frac{f(\sqrt{u})}{\sqrt{u}}\, du$ can be turned into $2\displaystyle\int f(v)\, dv$ by setting $v = \sqrt{u}$. Then $\operatorname{csch}^{2}$ is a derivative you probably should know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $v=\sqrt{u}$. Then, $dv = \dfrac1 {2 \sqrt{u}} \, du$, and you have $2 \int \operatorname{csch}^2 v \,dv$.

Now, use the fact that $(\coth x)' = -\operatorname{csch}^2 x$.

Comment: Should that be $(coth x)'=-csch^2 x$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try $t=\sqrt{u}$ and $dt=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$